# PostgreSQL not doing autoincrement

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I am using postgresql with springboot. So whenever I am using post method to add a new detail in my table instead of autoincrementing id it's going from 1 to 3. It's taking alternate values rather than consecutive values. I have given following properties and then created table:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
Didn't create the table manually. What is the reason for this error? This is my entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NORTHBOUND_SUBSCRIPTION")
public class NBSubscription {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "nb_id")
private Long nbId;

@Column(name = "DEVICE_FILTER")
private String deviceFilter;

@Column(name = "INTERFACE_FILTER")
private String interfaceFilter;

@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn(name="subscriber_id", referencedColumnName="SUBSCRIBER_ID")
private Subscriber subscriber;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="sensor_group_id", referencedColumnName="ID")
private SensorGroup sensorGroup;

@Column(name = "EVENT_TYPE")
private String eventType;

@Column(name = "SAMPLING_INTERVAL")
private Integer samplingInterval;

@Column(name = "CREATEAT")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
private Timestamp createAt;

@Column(name = "MODIFIEDAT")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
private Timestamp modifiedAt;

@Column(name = "CREATEDBY")
private String createdBy;

@Column(name = "MODIFIEDBY")
private String modifiedBy;

@Column(name = "mark_deletion")
private String markDeletion;


public NBSubscription() {
    super();
}
    
public NBSubscription(Subscriber subscriber, SensorGroup sensorGroup) {
    super();        
    this.subscriber = subscriber;
    this.sensorGroup = sensorGroup;
}



public Long getNbId() {
    return nbId;
}

public void setNbId(Long nbId) {
    this.nbId = nbId;
}

public String getDeviceFilter() {
    return deviceFilter;
}
public void setDeviceFilter(String deviceFilter) {
    this.deviceFilter = deviceFilter;
}
public String getInterfaceFilter() {
    return interfaceFilter;
}
public void setInterfaceFilter(String interfaceFilter) {
    this.interfaceFilter = interfaceFilter;
}

@JsonIgnore
public Subscriber getSubscriber() {
    return subscriber;
}
public void setSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber) {
    this.subscriber = subscriber;
}
public SensorGroup getSensorGroup() {
    return sensorGroup;
}
public void setSensorGroup(SensorGroup sensorGroup) {
    this.sensorGroup = sensorGroup;
}
public Integer getSamplingInterval() {
    return samplingInterval;
}
public void setSamplingInterval(Integer samplingInterval) {
    this.samplingInterval = samplingInterval;
}

public String getEventType() {
    return eventType;
}

public void setEventType(String eventType) {
    this.eventType = eventType;
}


    public Timestamp getCreateAt() {
    return createAt;
}

public void setCreateAt(Timestamp createAt) {
    this.createAt = createAt;
}

public Timestamp getModifiedAt() {
    return modifiedAt;
}

public void setModifiedAt(Timestamp modifiedAt) {
    this.modifiedAt = modifiedAt;
}

public String getMarkDeletion() {
    return markDeletion;
}

public void setMarkDeletion(String markDeletion) {
    this.markDeletion = markDeletion;
}

public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

public String getModifiedBy() {
    return modifiedBy;
}

public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
    this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
}
```

Comment: We cannot help because you havent provided relevant code how you do configure the autoincrement, ex. on the entity level thorugh annotations. What SO questions, documentation, blogs, tutorials, books have you consulted?

Comment: So it is doing autoincrement. It just isn't increasing the way you assumed it would. You are calling things an error which are working just fine.

Comment: I want id to get incremented like 1,2,3,4,5,.... but it's getting incremented like 1,3,5,7... is there any way so that i can increment it consecutively?

Comment: if all the entities are using the same sequence for autoincrements, your ids will be spread across the entities,  could that be what is happening?

Comment: Might be possible because in some table i am getting sequence as 1,3,5,7 and in another table sequence is 2,4,6,8. If this is the reason then can you please let me know what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

if it doesn't work, try using the table sequence

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="CUST_SEQ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your autoincrement is implemented with a sequence, and by default entities share the same sequence, so the autoincrement values get spread across the entities.

You could assign each entity its own sequence. But be aware sequences don't participate in transactions. That means if you have a rollback there will be a break in the numbering. Occasional gaps are not avoidable.

If you are making this sequence visible to users and they expect the numbering to be contiguous, my advice is to not use a sequence for that, and keep the user-visible counter in a field separate from the id. If it is visible to users, then at some point it will need to change, and you can't change ids.

Comment: thanks Nathan but it worked by using generationtype.identity